# Is their a way to move multiple vertices gradually at a time?

Tags: modeling, transforms, vertices

I have moved multiple vertices gradually but a set of vertices at a time not all at a time, as shown in the animation below (First I moved the four vertices from top, then three, then two and at last the last vertex).
 I wanted to do the same thing as shown in the animation below but all at a time.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the movement you want all at once with [proportional editing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit).

1. Select the top vertex
2. Press <kbd>O</kbd> to enable proportional editing
3. Change the [Falloff](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Proportional_Edit#Options) type to be either *linear* or *Smooth*.
4. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to move the vertices
5. While still moving the vertices, use the mouse wheel to change the size of the influence until it covers all the vertices you want to move.

[image: proportional editing]

Answer (score 2):

I think that David's solution would work very well for you. If you don't want to affect the nearest vertices just hide them with <kbd>H</kbd>. Changing the *Proportional Editing* type to ***Connected*** may be also helpful and work for you.

[image]