# Extruding an arc shape with a plane as the extrusion path

Tags: modeling

[image]

I created this model in AutoCAD and I am looking to recreate this design in blender.

To create the model I created two closed polylines and set there Z's. To draw the arc between the top and bottom plates the UCS can be aligned so that an arc can be drawn in 3D and then extruded along the top polyline to create this part that looks kind of like a lantern.

I am continuing to try to do this in Blender but I have not yet been able to achieve the design. Is this possible to model in Blender?

Thank You!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there could be many ways,  this is one :

- add a biziere curve align it to front view
- convert it to mesh with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>C</kbd>
- add a screw modifier
- set the steps to 4 (in the modifier)

[image]

Comment: Yes that looks like what I needed. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 3):

In Edit mode

1. Loop cut a cube 4 times around the Z axis <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `4` or scroll with <kbd>MMB [image: MMB]</kbd> to change the number of cuts.
2. Select the top 4 vertices then enable [proportional editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21133/2217), and change the *Falloff* to *Sphere*.
3. Press <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale along the X and Y axes.
4. Press <kbd>A</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select everything then scale along the Z <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: animated gif]