# How to deform a "plane"

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I really can't form this question, lol. So i'll post two images.
[image: What i have]
[image: What i get]

So first is the mesh. Second is somewhat what i want to do, but simple grab makes it wrong. Of course i need faces to rotate accordingly. Like taking a carton and bending it in hands.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Did you try using [proportional editing](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/proportional_edit.html) ? See [Is there a way to move multiple vertices gradually at a time](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21131/is-their-a-way-to-move-multiple-vertices-gradually-at-a-time)

Comment: proportional editing works better, but small surface deformation occurs nevertheless. i saw such shapes made in 3d models. are they made by hand (moving and rotating faces)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with a flat plane in “Top View”. Cut it in half and add a “Mirror Modifier”. Select the edge where you want the bend to take place then press “Shift” + “S” and select “Cursor to Selected” from the drop down menu.
[image]

Then change the “Pivot Center” to the 3D Cursor.

[image]

Then select the part of the plane you want to rotate and rotate around the 3D Cursor constrained to the “Y” axis. Press “R” + “Y” to accomplish this.

[image]

Then add a “Solidify Modifier”

[image]

Comment: great! forgot about the pivot thing. alternative method i just found would be hook to empty, but this is even better

Comment: yeah! that's seems to be the thing about modeling "flat" forms! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found a soulution - there are propably better ways, but here you go:

- Select only one side of the selected faces in your screenshot.
- Press <kbd>P</kbd> and select *Seperate by Selection*. Now these faces are a second object.
- Select the first object. Select **edit: not all verts, only those that are where the 'wing' or whatever is - the rotation axis should be** verts and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> and select *Cursor to selected*.
- Now select the second object again and (this time in object mode) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> (do it with two hands ;) *I know, it's a pain*) and select *Origin to 3D cursor*.
  *what this does is set the origin of the second object to where you want to rotate it around, as the objects origin defines it's rotation axis.*
- Now just rotate Object 2 around the Y axis in your example and there you go.
- Do this for both sides and then join the objects back together with both selected and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>.
- From there you have to connect the edges and faces to the rotated faces (wich is suitable for low vertex counts, but for more complex meshes you'll have to find another and propably way simpler method).

Comment: you're right. i suggested you to reconnect them manually. so that you got the rotation right. i know, overly complicated, as i said

Comment: connecting vertices causes frustration lol. if i got you right, i have now flat main mesh with removed faces, that are placed over at correct position. but how can i now connect lower vertices with upper? one by one?

Comment: yeah.. with your mesh this takes 10 secs, but for more complex meshes i have no clue and i'm waiting for some better method

Comment: thanks! when i was asking this, i was thinking that i'm missing something obvious