# What's the name of this Tool/Feature?

Tags: mesh, sculpting

In advance: newbie here, thanks for your help! I used to play around with NURBS in Maya and loved this feature where I could mold the object like clay- pushing and pulling with a red/yellow mapping of the strength. Though, I don't remember what the tool is called or if its even the same for mesh/Blender.
I have a model I want to move uniformly instead of just the faces/vertices I select- which gives long, hard lines instead of a gradient. Example: I need to move the arm up in a T-pose, but if I select it to rotate and generally manipulate it, there's an unnatural edge to where my selection starts/ends. How do I get the option to click a point, see the radius of strength, and then push/pull so it moves all in the radius uniformly?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's proportional editing.  press **o** to enable it.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21131/is-their-a-way-to-move-multiple-vertices-gradually-at-a-time

Comment: Blender do support **NURBS** BTW. But it is not that simple compare to polygon vertices.